# Creaking sound when I turn steering wheel at low speeds

Tags: noise, power-steering, steering

I have a 2006 Jeep Liberty and yesterday I noticed a creaking noise coming from the front end.

I am editing my question because I have made more observations. The creaking happens almost anytime I turn the steering wheel. It happens when I am parked or moving. I think I may have heard it just barely when going over bumps, but not positive about that. It is more noticeable at low speeds and when I slowly turn the steering wheel.

I've never looked at steering or suspension before, so I am hoping for a few diagnostic procedures I could take to try and narrow down the issue so I can get it fixed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creaking sound is too large to assume.
There is so much possibility of what happens with your car,
But I have this same kind of problem back in 2016.

Possible procedure to narrow it down:

- Turn on your engine in neutral position, turn your steering wheel first left and right after that do rev your engine, while you rev turn your steer. If you found creaking noise like a rat either on rev or not, it is possible your hydraulic steering system needs service.
- If you didn't find any. try to jack your front wheel (the steering wheel not the drive wheel)  don't forget to hand brake and put something like rock close behind the rear wheel for safety :) after that try to shake the sway bar, lower and upper bar (if you have), and check if the tie rod is a bit loose. if the sway bar is shaken that's probably your bushing for a sway bar is worn out.

Another possibility :

- Your tire is worn out. it will make a noise like creaking as you stated.
- Or your rim is loose (this is extra rare although it happened)

Check carefully, if you want to try it alone for this kind of procedure please don't overconfidence. **Always safety first. Never jack your car while the engine is running**. **Don't leave anything like a car key near your child, especially near the jack. If you jack the car even with a branded hydraulic jack please don't put your head below your car**

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did what you said and found out that the noise was coming from the lower ball joint on the driver's side. Glad it wasn't the steering itself!

Comment: I'm very glad you found your problems quickly. it didn't do well with mine, because last time i need to replace the tie rod, all kinds of bushing for the sway bar, and it should be replacing the tire hub (the tire hub it's out of budget :D)